# Symfony / Twig - Recursion decrease db queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have my category tree in twig template:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <li>
        <div class="li"><a href="{{ path('accessories_list', { 'category' : category.url }) }}">{{ category.name|trans({}, 'categories')|raw }}</a></div>
        {% if category.children is not empty %}
            <ul>
                {% include "default/_menu_links.html.twig" with {'categories':category.children} only %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

It creates +- 53 database queries if I have 6 categories and 7 subcategories in each single category.

Is there a way to decrease that number? 
I'm using useResultCache(true) in doctrine, but looks like it's not loading from the cache(at least not in dev mode).

How are you handling category trees?

UPDATE: 
Entity:

```
...
    /**
     * One Category has Many Subcategories.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"}))
     */
    private $children;
    /**
     * Many Subcategories have One Category.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;
...
    /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Category $child
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addChild(\App\Entity\Product\Category $child): Category
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Category $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\App\Entity\Product\Category $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren(): Collection
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Category $parent
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParent(\App\Entity\Product\Category $parent = null): Category
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\Product\Category
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }
...
```

Comment: Usually if the amount of your database queries depends on the fetched data (more data=more queries), you should consider using JOIN statements to decrease database queries. It would be helpful if you could provide some code of your doctrine entities.

Comment: @radon66 Hi thanks for the reply. Updated my question. So you think it would be better once per day generate categories in json, cache it and use on website?

Answer (score 0):

According to my comment: you have to `JOIN`your subcategories. I'm assuming you are currently doing something like this to retrieve your `categories`:

```
   public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("category")
            ->from("App:Category", "category")
            ->where("category.parent IS NULL")
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
     }
```

So if you are now iterating over this array of categories and trying to access the `children` property, a sub query will be fired for each children which causes this high amount of database queries.

Instead you should `JOIN` them like this:

```
 public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select("category", "subcat")
            ->from("App:Category", "category")
            ->leftJoin("category.children", "subcat")
            ->where("category.parent IS NULL")
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

If you now iterate over your `categories` and access the `children` property, no extra query will be fired!

Using the query above and this snippet in twig will result only in one database query:

```
   {% for category in categories %}
        <p>cat={{ category.id }}</p>

        {% for subcat in category.children %}
            <p>subcat={{ subcat.id }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, tried your solution and getting the same amount of queries. Maybe I should just fetch it into a json and cache.

Comment: You could do that, but this would not really solve the problem. Could you please post your code how your `categories` are retrieved? Using my above code works fine using a fresh symfony installation. `leftJoin` is the important method!